# Python 2D Lists in For Loops

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-lists

I have built a 2D list (I still want to call it an array) to hold information about currency tokens as such:

```
Token = [["P",0,.01,"Penny"],["N",0,.05,"Nickel"],["D",0,.10,"Dime"],["Q",0,.25,"Quarter"]]
```

When I try to read the value of a token using this code:

```
for i in Token:
    print (Token[i][3])
```

I am given an error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

I'm not sure I understand the error, and have not had much success searching online for a solution.  Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

If it helps, code for the [whole project is on GitHub](https://github.com/nwautier/RPICoinCounter/commit/908f41f4afd05b8ae53d817707d57c03191cb039).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a for-each loop which, in Python, will give you the item in the list, not an index. Also, you are using a set of sets, which is not valid syntax. Therefore, keep a list of list and just use one index:

```
Token =  [["P",0,.01,"Penny"],["N",0,.05,"Nickel"],["D",0,.10,"Dime"],["Q",0,.25,"Quarter"]]

for i in Token:
   print(i[3])
```

Comment: You can't index `set`s... : Your code throws `TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. As @Cory Madden mentioned, the OP appears to have a C++ background, and is probably using a list of lists. I will convert the sets to lists in my answer for clarity, however.

Comment: Yup, my curly braces were simply a typo.  I'm a self-taught VB Programmer...  AKA, not really a programmer!  Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

For each iteration through Token you're getting that item as `i`. So on your first iteration:

```
for i in Token:
```

i = ["P",0,.01,"Penny"]

Just do:

```
for i in Token:
    print i[3]
```